# How do you XMLSerialize a more complex class in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

hello I want to serialize a class in C# with a XMLserializer. The Compiler says that Room (myClass) is not primitive (i am using Unity3d) and therefor can not be serialized. The problem is that the most Tutorial are only for simple classes with a few simple fields. Can you help me changs Room to be serializable?

```
[Serializable]
public class Room
{
public Room()
{
    m_id = "test";
    m_section = Areas.PublicSec;
    m_connections = null;
    m_size = 10;
}
public Room(string _id, Areas _section, List<string> _connections, int _size)
{
    // f.e. Bathroom
    m_id = _id;

    // private, public or hallway filled with the enum Areas
    m_section = _section;

    // list of rooms that have or will have a Connection
    if (_connections != null)
    {
        m_connections = _connections;
    }
    else 
    {
        m_connections = new List<string>();
    }

 //? Desired minium size of the room
    m_size = _size;
}

private string m_id;
public string id
{
    get { return m_id; }
    set { m_id = value;}
}

private Areas m_section;
public Areas Section
{
    get { return m_section; }
    set { m_section = value; }

}

private List<string> m_connections;
[XmlArray("m_connections")]
public List<string> Connections
{
    get { return m_connections; }
    set { m_connections = value; }

}

private int m_size;
public int Size
{
    get { return m_size; }
    set { m_size = value; }

}
}
```

My XMLSerializer works with simple classes but not with this one.

Comment: What is `Areas`, that also must be serializeable (or set to `XmlIgnore`)

Comment: If `Areas` is also serializable add the `XmlInclude` attribute to the `Room` class, `[XmlInclue(typeof(Areas))]`